# How can you add thousand separator when formatting a number in Cheetah?

Tags: python-3.x, cheetah

I'm trying to format a number as a price in Cheetah3 (Python 3.6). While I have succeeded to limit to 2 decimals using the standard formatting expression, the comma separator doesn't seem to work (I get an error).

**Cheetah Expression**:

```
#def format_price($price)
    #if $price < 0.0
        #set $price_str = '($%,.2f)' % (-1.0 * $price)
    #else
        #set $price_str = '$%,.2f' % $price
    #end if
    $price_str
#end def
```

**Error**:

```
ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Cheetah problem. That `ValueError` comes directly from Python:

```
$ python3.6
>>> '($%,.2f)' % -1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 3
```

You probably want `.format()`.